# Git Commit error 'error: cannot spawn gpg1: No such file or directory'

Tags: git, github, version-control, commit, gnupg

I'm trying to commit files with GitHub Desktop(also tried with Android Studio VCS and Git Bash) and every time I get with error. Tried to reinstall git and gpg - unsuccessfully. Help please to solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

[image]